# Help with SQL statement (JOIN)

Tags: sql, join

I'm having some trouble with an SQL statement that have to find the number of students attending a course.
My Database design look likes this:

Table **Course:**
id | course_name

Table **Student:**
id | name

And to connect the two many-to-many relationship I've an table:

Table **course_student:**
id | course_id | student_id

What I want is to find out how many students are attending the course named "Database Design". I know that the ID is "1" but let’s say that I didn't knew, how would my SQL statement look like?

I have tried several different statements with different joins to first select the correct ID from the **course** table, where the name is "Database Design" and next I've to search in my **course_student** table where the course_id equal the founded id (in this case 1) and where all student_id is connected to this id.

I know it is a bit complex description so please tell me if I have to explain it in a better way.

Thanks
Mestika

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try something like

```
SELECT  COUNT(cs.student_id)
FROM    Course c INNER JOIN
        course_student cs ON c.id = cs.course_id
WHERE   c.course_name = 'Database Design'
```

You dont have to join to the Students table as you already have the ID in the course_student table, so 1 less join.

Comment: darn you and your typing skills

Comment: Good one, @astander.  Was working it out when you posted.  GJ.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(a.id)
FROM Course a
INNER JOIN Course_Student b
ON a.id = b.course_id
WHERE a.course_name = 'Database Design'
```

Comment: Looks like astander beat me to it.

Comment: for the second example, you would not even have to join to the table *Course*.

Answer (score 0):

just a slightly different style, but same results

`select COUNT(cs.student_id) as counter
from Course c, course_student cs
where c.id = cs.course_id
and c.course_name = 'Database Design'`

Comment: Implicit joins are bad. Please don't encourage the use of this poor techinique.

Comment: I have used the technique very successfully for a long time.  Please explain what is in error with this.